# Roundoff without builtin method

Tags: c#, rounding

I want to roundoff a float variable to int, without using any builtin method. 
This will be like

```
13.4 => 13
13.49 => 13
13.5 => 14
13.6 => 14
```

So far this is the closest I could reach to but not sure if this is efficient.

```
int Roundoff(float num)
{
    int temp = (int) num;

    num *= 10;
    if(num%10 >= 5)
    {
        return temp + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return temp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
int Roundoff(float num) {
  return num < 0 ? (int) (num - 0.5) : (int) (num + 0.5);
}
```

There is a **trick** with *negative values* (you can't just add `0.5`):

```
  -13.9 -> -14.0
  -13.1 -> -13
```

And *be careful*, since

```
  int.MaxValue < float.MaxValue
  int.MinValue > float.MinValue
```

Comment: Although I didn't mention handling negative values but marking it as answer as it covers both. Riz's explanation helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Well you are already using casting and sometime this can give you exactly what you need.
If you simply add 0.5 in your number and then cast to integer, you will get the rounded value.

```
13.4 + 0.5 = 13.9 -> 13 (when casted to int)
13.49 + 0.5 = 13.99 -> 13
13.5 + 0.5 = 14.0 -> 14
13.6 + 0.5 = 14.1 -> 14
```

This is how you would write the method.

```
int Roundoff(float num)
{
    return (int) (num + 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float f = 0.3;  // Or whatever
int i = (int) (f + 0.5f);
```